# Jodit table border color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, wysiwyg, jodit

When you create a table in Jodit Editor, the table doesn't have any styling. We have the option to select border color for cells. If i select all the cells and assign a color, we can see the color in editor.
[Table cells with black borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmpG8.png)

But it doesn't reflect in preview.

[Transparent borders in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBLV9.png)

Any lead on how to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: if i understood this correctly, i think you should check the html code generated by the Jodit component and see if the border colors have been overridden by your application css

Answer (score 0):

because the table doesn't have border style.

Comment: Is there any way to change the border style?. a customer toolbar button option or other config?